# Temporarily freeze a process upon shell interaction

Tags: shell, kill, prompt, tail

Let's say on a single console I have tail -F running, showing the output of many log files in realtime.

Sometimes I need to run commands there too, however, and examine their output briefly, without getting sprinkled over by the bursts of tail output.

What might be a nifty way to `killall -STOP tail` (or otherwise *temporarily* suspend *automatically*) upon some interaction with the console (or at least pressing ENTER, which invokes the PROMPT command, etc.), and delay the `killall -CONT tail` by 90 seconds *after* the latest shell interaction?

Previously, I had been doing manually:

```
fg  # to tail process
```

## manually press CTRL Z

```
run my command,see output

bg  # to tail process
```

Comment: Have you looked into `screen` or `tmux` ? It won't do the SIGSTP but it should work around the actual issue you have.

Answer (score 1):

On many Unix-like systems, including Linux, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is the most common default keyboard mapping for the key sequence that suspends a process (SIGTSTP).

`fg` will resume the process in the foreground.

---

**Edit**

Using the `blankerprg` directive in screen you can define a "screensaver" program for your terminal. You can define it interactively from within screen with:

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `blankerprg tail -f /path/to/log`

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> `idle 10 blanker`

After being idle for 10 seconds the screensaver you defined will kick in and hit any key-press will disable it.

Those settings can also be added in the `~/.screenrc` of course.

Comment: Yes but how to make that happen automatically upon any shell interaction?  (and not forget to automatically send the SIGCONT later, either). That's what my question is about.

Comment: Ah, right. You want your tail command to behave like a sort of screensaver. That requires some premeditation: rather then work directly in your terminal I recommend getting in the habbit of working in the `screen` terminal multiplexer. Within screen where you can configure a `blankerprg` that will act as such.

Comment: Nay; I'm not looking to change my habits.
`screen` doesn't play well with any terminal program, btw. (Try scrolling up in Putty, for instance).

Comment: As I said it requires changing your habits like piping your output to `less`. But when working with flaky connections the bad far outweighs the good...  And it does give you the nifty console screensaver ;)

Comment: A cleaner & simpler solution would be to include a `killall -STOP tail; sleep 90 && killall -CONT tail&` in PROMPT_COMMAND. That is almost all! Except I want to see in this SE how others might address the issue of how to keep postponing that CONT as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the current job (the last job that was stopped or resumed) with

```
kill -STOP %%
```

I don't think reacting after a number of seconds of inactivity is possible in bash. In zsh, you can set the `TMOUT` parameter to a number, which causes the shell to execute the `ALRM` trap after that `$TMOUT` seconds of inactivity. (Bash has a `TMOUT` activity but it causes the shell to exit.)

The following zsh snippet defines a function that suspends the current background job until 90 seconds of inactivity have occurred, and binds this function to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

```
suspend_background_job_during_activity () {
  job=${1-%%}
  kill -STOP $job
  TMOUT=90
  trap "fg $job; unset TMOUT; trap - ALRM" ALRM
}
zle -N suspend_background_job_during_activity
bindkey '^X^Z' suspend_background_job_during_activity
```

Comment: Good tip! So maybe a wrapper script can be written in BASH that traps its ALRM and sends a SIGCONT to something else. Put that feature to some good use :)